# how to combine d1 all rows and d1 all rows and save in dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

lst1 = [1,2,3,5,8,9,10,11]

lst2 = [4,5,6,8,9,17,19,29,37]

for i in lst1:
d1 = driver.find_element("xpath", f'//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_TabPanel1"]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]')

```
print(d1.text)
sleep(1)
```

driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="__tab_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_TabPanel2"]/span').click()

sleep(2)

for j in lst2:
d2 = driver.find_element("xpath", f'//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_TabPanel2"]/table/tbody/tr[{j}]')

```
print(d2.text)
sleep(1)
```

Comment: can you share the url with us, this will be easier by saving the entire table at once

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.